# Partially mock `react-native` module

Tags: react-native, jestjs

I'm running unit tests in React Native that need the `NativeEventEmitter` and `NativeModules` mocked but leave everything else as passthrough to the real code.

This part seems to be working except when running I get this error.

```
    Invariant Violation: TurboModuleRegistry.getEnforcing(...): 'DevSettings' could not be found. Verify that a module by this name is registered in the native binary.

      at invariant (../node_modules/invariant/invariant.js:40:15)
      at Object.getEnforcing (../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/TurboModule/TurboModuleRegistry.js:39:3)
      at Object.<anonymous> (../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/NativeModules/specs/NativeDevSettings.js:30:37)
      at Object.<anonymous> (../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Utilities/DevSettings.js:10:1)
```

Mocking:

```
jest.mock(
  'react-native',
  () => ({
    ...jest.requireActual('react-native'),
    NativeEventEmitter: class MockNativeEventEmitter {
      // ...
    },
    NativeModules: {
      // ...
    },
    Platform: {
      OS: 'android',
    },
  })
);
```

Online searches for this error all point to problems compiling in dev vs release mode, nothing remotely close to what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried importing `DevSettings` from react-native and adding the same imported module in your mock? This would be the process for every Component/Module being used in your tested component. Something like:

```
import { DevSettings } from 'react-native`

jest.mock(
  'react-native',
  () => ({
    ...jest.requireActual('react-native'),
    NativeEventEmitter: class MockNativeEventEmitter {
      // ...
    },
    NativeModules: {
      // ...
    },
    Platform: {
      OS: 'android',
    },
    DevSettings
  })
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. After your post I tried that and also tried mocking out `DevSettings` and `TurboModuleRegistry` and neither worked. Mocking `TurboModuleRegistry` did fix this and any native module failed to load errors, but then lots of other things break, like `Dimensions` throughs an error `Cannot read property 'getConstants' of undefined`

Comment: have you found an answer to this question?